# Reading numbers from AWS Lambda and plot in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a python program on AWS Lambda that will count and print out number of EC2 instances (no_of_instance) with a specific tag (myTagName), how can I push this number to CloudWatch / read this number from CloudWatch so that I can plot the number on CloudWatch graph and monitor the number of running instances over time?

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    Filter = [{'Name': 'tag:Name','Values': ['myTagName']}]
    response = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=Filter)
    instance_info = response["Reservations"]
    no_of_instance = len(instance_info)
    print(no_of_instance)   # int type
```

Comment: https://stackify.com/custom-metrics-aws-lambda/

Comment: Alternatively: [Creating metrics from log events using filters](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html)